# Why does Item menu text disappear after setAction method is called?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, menu, action

I have added an action to itemMenu using the setAction method below, but when I execute the code, the text of this menu item disappears.  The code works fine, since clicking in the location of this menu item causes the action to be executed.

```
exit.setAction(new AbstractAction() {
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
     System.exit(0);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass in the name of the button or menu item to the constructor of the action:

```
// Note the AbstractAction constructor can take a String
exit.setAction(new AbstractAction("Exit"){ 
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
     System.exit(0);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this for multiple menu items:

```
JMenuItem firstMenuItem = new JMenuItem("First");  
JMenuItem secondMenuItem = new JMenuItem("Second");  

ActionListener commanAction = new ActionListener() {  
    @Override  
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {  
        if(ae.getSource().equals(firstMenuItem)) {  
               // Do Something....  
        } else if(ae.getSource().equals(secondMenuItem)) {  
               // Do Something....  
        }  
    }  
};  
firstMenuItem.addActionListener(commanAction);  
secondMenuItem.addActionListener(commanAction);
```